# Design forum in MVC pattern?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a forum in php & MySQL for intranet.I started my development by creating a DAO from my database operation then In my all php pages i use scriplets with in the html code to fetch data i require from my DAO.

```
 <htlm>
<body>
<table>
<tr><th>Subject</th><th>By</th><th>Date</th></tr>
<?php 
    $posts=DAO.getPostDAO().getPostByUserId(userId);
   for($i=0;$i<count($posts);$i++)
   {
  $post=$posts[$i];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $post->subject; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $post->userId; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $post->createdAt; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I have red about MVC pattern ,I understand the concept but I dont know how to implement it while writing code so can you help me to convert this to MVC pattern.
Can you tell me how should i divide this in to module,view and controller and where does the DAO fit in all this? Is is a part of controller?

Comment: MVC is not something that can be answered in response to a random little block of HTML and PHP.  It's a whole way of architecting an application, nothing to do with a single little script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggsest you use an existing PHP MVC framework ([Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), ...) and learn from that.

Your question is just to big to answer here, whole books are written on the subject. By using and studying an existing solution you'll learn everything you need, and will (probably) be able to roll your own framework once you're done.

Comment: I have completed 50% of my development so I was hoping to convert my code to MVC pattern,Because of my current structure i have written lot of complex javascript and DB queries which i want to get rid of if i can.

Comment: Like I said your question is just to big to answer. Take a look at the frameworks I listed, read their documentation and then try to figure out by yourself on how to transform your code to use the MVC pattern.

Comment: Thanks jan for ur reply ,Will look in to it

Answer (score 0):

Another MVC project. Excellent documentation and extensive features. I've used it for learning about MVC my self and found it useful.
http://www.phalconphp.com/en/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.